# What is the background track in this trailer?

Tags: classical-music

I saw this trailer about 5 years ago and recently I've been wanting to find the trailer song to it because it's driving me nuts haha.

I'm 99% sure the music was only released FOR the trailer but if anyone can recommend any pieces similar to the background track, i'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi Lily, identifying music is no longer on-topic on this site. You might want to try Reddit's [NameThatSong](https://www.reddit.com/r/NameThatSong/).